# Linker Error (Clang)

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

ld: '/Users/rehaanadvani/Downloads/parse-library-1/Parse.framework/Parse(PFACL.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I get this error when I try to build my Xcode project. I already checked that I have bitcode enabled, so what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Parse library has bitcode disabled but your project has bitcode enabled. But the settings have to match. Either rebuild Parse with bitcode or disable bitcode in your project.